# Find Parent List Paragraph in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I find the parent list paragraph of any given list paragraph. So in:

1. Blah1

   a.  Blah2

   ```
     i.    Blah3

     ii.   Blah4
   ```

   b.  Blah5

How could I find the parent of say ii. Blah 4 (being a. Blah2 in this simple example)?

I know I cannot simply loop through the list paragraphs looking for a list paragraph the next list level up from what I am at, because it will go wrong when you have nested lists. I am also conscious that I have seen documents in the past where there are more than one list within the same list template. For this reason I don't think it is possible to loop through all the items in a list and pick the item previous to the one I am at, because they could be in different lists.

Comment: Is the VSTO tag appropriate for this question? There's nothing in it specific to that technology...

Comment: Well you can program Word with VBA or VSTO so I think it probably is relevant

Comment: VSTO is a technology that extends the Word object model. It adds nothing to Word in this respect, so is not relevant to the question. VSTO is only useful when using the VSTO technology and the question has to do with that technology. It's irrelevant when discussing "how Word works".

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good question - the object model of Word's numbering system is anything but transparent!

Actually, you can loop through a specific list's paragraph members, even when another list is "nested" inside it, using the `ListParagraphs` collection.

Since you want to "move up" in the list, it makes sense to loop from bottom-to-top. The code sample below gets the paragraph and its Range from the current selection. Then it tries to pick up the Range's `ListFormat.List`. If the selection is not part of a list, the object variable is `Nothing` and the code exits.

Otherwise, the list level of the selection and the number of ListParagraphs in the list is determined. The latter provides the information for looping backwards through the paragraphs in the list. To test whether the `ListParagraph` in the loop is the same as that of the selection, use the `Range.InRange` method. This is combined with a boolean that holds whether the loop has hit the selection. When both criteria are true, the boolean is set to True.

In subsequent loops, with the boolean true and the list level number of the `ListParagraph` in the loop is "above" (lower number is higher in the hierarchy) that of the current selection, then the paragraph you want is found and is selected; the loop is exited.

```
Sub LoopParagraphsOfList()
    Dim rngSel As word.Range
    Dim lst As word.List, nrListParas As Long
    Dim lstPara As word.Paragraph
    Dim curPara As word.Paragraph
    Dim selLevel As Long, paraCounter As Long
    Dim bStartingPoint As Boolean

    bStartingPoint = False
    Set curPara = Selection.Paragraphs(1)
    Set rngSel = curPara.Range
    Set lst = rngSel.ListFormat.List
    If lst Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "The current selection is not part of a list"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    selLevel = rngSel.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
    nrListParas = lst.ListParagraphs.Count
    For paraCounter = nrListParas To 1 Step -1
        Set lstPara = lst.ListParagraphs(paraCounter)
        If lstPara.Range.InRange(curPara.Range) And Not bStartingPoint Then
            bStartingPoint = True
        End If
        If bStartingPoint And lstPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber < selLevel Then
            lstPara.Range.Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Cindy but your code doesn't work in all examples. If I test on a document that has one list template but multiple lists (according to vba although Word treats them as one list) then the code doesn't work. I believe the multiple lists are due different styles on different list paragraphs, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I created a test with a "list within a list", the way you described. You need to give exact repro information, as well as any code you've tried that hasn't worked with a description about HOW it doesn't work, so that no one wastes their time.

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to waste anyone's time, I appreciate any help. Your code addresses nested lists part of my question but not the bit about multiple lists within the same list template. I’ve only seen this in client docs and not sure how to recreate it. So I stripped down an ex doc put it here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=36011208724286474336 VBA says there are 2 lists in the doc but all the numbers move consistently when you add in new levels, so Word knows they are all connected (ie 1 list template). Your code only runs through the 1 list so doesn’t get LP’s in other lists